# how to get previous view when entered in foreground in ios

Tags: ios

i've a chat view,i'm chating with someone and when i enter in background,and once again enter in foreground all message have been removed(refresh),how can i got same chat message.

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];


    SPHViewController *chatView = [[SPHViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SPHViewController" bundle:nil];
    chatView.strCallerName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",strSelectedCallerName];
    self.window.rootViewController = chatView;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: I've gone through this process.. you'll need to repopulate the chatView once the app opens.

Comment: how to repopulate chat view..@AhmedZ.

Comment: are u using any storage to save the messages?

Comment: I used core data to store the messages as they were sent or received with sender(that would be u) and receiver id and would repopulate it on based on those Ids combination.

Comment: i've only SPHViewController

Answer (score 1):

You are basically resetting the app state every time the app enters foreground. That's not the place to instantiate your view controller and set the app's main window. You need to do that in your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`